# how to get a value from a filtered values of dataview in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, dataview

I have a filtered data view, from which I have to extract the values. Problem is that when I do this, I am getting the values from non filtered data also.

```
dv1.RowFilter = "collegeno=" +i; 
for(int k=1;k<dv1.count;k++)  
 {  
   //inserting data in database; there is column in database table; I am inserting into it;
 dv1.Table.Rows[k]["roomno"]);

 }
```

*For ex*: The total no. of rows in DataView is `200`;
When `i=1` I have `30` records;
If I supply `k=4`, then I should get fourth row from this `30` records.
But I am getting 4th row of the `200` records..

Comment: Please add more code !

Comment: Could you please explain more on `RowFilter`

Comment: @user3116746 updated question's code is syntactically wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written is accessing the main table using the code block `dv1.Table`.

Instead try as this

```
dv1[k]["roomno"]
```

This code works on `DataView`, on which the filter is applicable.

If you use `DataView.Table` then it will access the non-filtered results.

Reference Link: [MSDN - DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> If I supply k=4, then I should get fourth row from this 30 records.
>   But I am getting 4th row of the 200 records..

That's because you're querying the table, not the view. Instead you should do this:

```
dv1.RowFilter = "collegeno=" +i; 
object value = dv1[k]["roomno"];
```

Depending on what you need, you might want to use the DataTable.Select method instead of a `DataView`:

```
var rows = table.Select("collegeno=" +i);
object value = rows[k]["roomno"];
```

Comment: kindly let me know, which one is better in performance "Datatable.select" or Dataview??

Comment: @user3116746, I'd say that DataView is a bit faster, since it doesn't materialize the filtered rows, but that's just a guess; you should do some profiling if you want to be sure. Anyway, unless you have a lot of data in the table, the difference is probably small; use the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();     
     for(int k=1;k<dt.Rows.Count;k++)  
     {  
        dt.Rows[k]["roomno"];
       //dv1.Table.Rows[k]["roomno"]);

     }
```

Comment: Actually, this is still not valid because an indexer access is not a statement, but the OP's code was not valid either...